# Is React Testing Library the right tool for testing parts of the app with no effect on UI?

Tags: reactjs, enzyme, react-testing-library

I'm working on updating an app that was originally built in React 16 and all front-end tests were created with Enzyme. I have updated to React 17 and started rewriting all the tests using React Testing Library. This worked fine for UI components, but I'm really struggling to figure out how to rewrite tests for some of the methods on the main `App` component.

Basically the app is a webform, which submits the same set of user-entered data to 2 different databases. A lot of the processing and reformatting of the data in preparation for the API calls happens on the front end. So after the user clicks 'submit', there are a bunch of methods called inside `handleSubmit`.

- One method fetches a token and verifies a recaptcha score using
  `react-google-invisible-recaptcha`
- One method cleans up and formats data to prepare for the POST to database 1
- One method does the same for database 2
- One method makes the POST call to database 1
- One method POSTs to database 2 (using an id returned from database 1 so
  this has to happen sequentially)
- One method collects any errors returned from either POST call and updates the record in db 1 with a success or failure flag
- One method checks to see if all the operations were successfully completed and then navigates the user to the next tab of the form

In the old app I was able to get code coverage for all these sequential steps in Enzyme by calling each method programmatically (eg `wrapper.instance().verifyRecaptchaScore` or `wrapper.instance().createSubmission`) with different sets of props and then testing whether errors were handled as expected, or if a method was successful if the next method in the chain was called in sequence.

But since React Testing Library is only meant to be used to test results that are visible in the UI, I can't figure out how to test any of this. If the submission is successful, the only effect visible to the front end user is that they are navigated to the next tab of the form. If there is an error, the user gets a snackbar message, but the message doesn't tell them the name of the method that caused the error since this isn't useful information to the user.

So I guess my question is, is React Testing Library the right tool for this kind of testing? If so, how would you approach it? Or should I just use RTL for testing the simple UI components and stick with Enzyme for testing the `handleSubmit` and associated methods? I think Enzyme is no longer going to work with React at all once I upgrade to React 18 though so this seems like a dead end. Are there other alternatives?